# Refresh token expiration dates

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

Is it common for Oauth2 refresh tokens to expire?

I have a project that consumes two API's. After no activity for about 2 months, my refresh tokens don't work when I'm trying to fetch a new access token. I receive a "invalid grant: the refresh token has expired"-response.

What should I do to go around this, so that I don't have to re-authenticate each time this happens. A cron that refreshes the tokens each week?

I thought refresh tokens generally worked until revoked?

Comment: Does OAuth documentation / support not yield anything regarding this? It might be better to use those channels first.

Comment: @Script47 Do you mean the Oauth documentation for each API, or some general Oauth documentation? The Oauth2 parts of the API docs doesn't mention any expiration for the refresh tokens..